# Error when installing pygame

Tags: 18.04, python

When I type `import pygame` in Thonny I get an error. I installed `pygame` with `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`, but it's not working. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have python3 as your default python version while the python library you installed is for python2

You can verify this by running:

`python --version`

if you don't have python2:

`apt-get install python2.7`

then explicitly start python2.7 and run  import pygame from there